# Why is "He climbed the mountain up" incorrect?

Tags: adverb-position, transitive-verbs

Now I know, because an adverb cannot be placed between a verb and its direct object, the only way we parse "He climbed up the mountain" is as an intransitive verb (climb) + prepositional phrase (up the mountain).

But why is "He climbed the mountain up" incorrect?
I read when there is a direct object after a transitive verb, adverbs can be placed after that direct object.

He (subject) + climbed (transitive verb) + the mountain (direct object) + up (an adverb).
So I think the adverb "up" can be placed after the direct object "mountain."

Please explain to me grammatically why we cannot have "up" after "the mountain".

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Because _climb up_ is not a phrasal verb that undergoes inversion, like _look up_. You can _look the word up_ or you can _look up the word_, but with pronouns, it only works one way: _look it up_, not *_look up it_. That's **one** kind of verb + preposition. But _climb up_ is like _look at_ -- the preposition doesn't make it a phrasal verb, and there's no inversion. You can't say *_She looked it at_ or *_She climbed it up_. There is no "Why?"; that's just the way English verbs are -- there are many types and they have to be learned individually, like Chinese characters.

Comment: @JohnLawler Good to read. I only add, almost irrelevantly, that English is not like German, where the preposition may go at the end. "We climbed up the hill" -> "Wir stiegen den Hügel hinauf", which translates literally and incorrectly as "We climbed the hill up".

Comment: Unless you're using a more prescriptive definition of 'phrasal verb' (the confusing and unhelpful polysemy of the term has been discussed on ELU on various occasions), there are certainly inseparable examples. _This calls for caution._ / _I came by my old school cap the other day._ / _Let's go over the plan one more time._

Comment: What is different is that, while _up_ can be an adverb, it is more often either a preposition or a particle in a phrasal verb. If you put it in that position in the sentence, it sounds as if it is a separably particle (like _I moved the entry up_ or _I woke my friend up_), and that blocks its interprtation as a free adverb.  But _climb up_ does not allow that separation, so the sentence is not grammatical.

Comment: @John Lawler Non-phrasal transitive verbs can have adverbs too--after their direct object--right?  I am using the word "up" as an adverb.  Then why is "He climbed the mountain up" incorrect?  How is "He climbed the mountain up" different from "He climbed the mountain slowly," or "He played the piano very well" in terms of grammar?  In all sentences the grammar composition is Subject + transitive verb + direct object + adverb.

Comment: Because there are rules about where adverbs can be placed. In *He climbed up onto the table,* it's clear that *up* is an adverb (because it's not part of a two-word preposition *up onto*, since no such two-word preposition exists). However, you can't say *He climbed onto the table up*, because we can't put *up* there. Adverbial placement in English is quite complicated, and depends on the type of adverb.

Comment: @Colin Fine  Very valuable information.  So far, that's the closest to the answer I've been looking for.  So "Up" as an adverb, can not be placed after a direct object?  And the only way "up" can be placed after a direct object is as a particle?  And if that's true, then "Up", as an adverb, can only be used with intransitive verbs and come only after intransitive verbs.  Is this right?  Adverbs like "exactly," "gently," "well" can come after direct object, but "Up" can't.  So depending on the characteristic of an adverb, its position differs?  Is there a grammar that explains this?

Comment: @AS: No, because *I took the elevator up* is a perfectly grammatical English sentence.

Comment: @Peter Shor  So "Up," as an adverb, can not be placed after a direct object?  Can you read the comment I made to Colin Fine and give me more information please?  I am already satisfied though.

Comment: "Up" can be placed after *elevator* in *I took the elevator up*. So sometimes *up* can be placed after a direct object. But I don't understand the grammar that lets you do that.

Comment: @Peter Shor But isn't "Take up" a phrasal verb, and "Up" in "I took the elevator up" a particle?  If "Take up" is not a phrasal verb here, and "Up" is not a particle, but just an adverb, I don't know how the "Up" in "I took the elevator up" is different from the "Up" in "He climbed the mountain up."

Comment: Not entirely sure why, but *he climbed the mountain up* made an image pop into my head - of a man puppeteering a mountain into climbing up something else. When the preposition comes after something, I generally expect that something to have been affected somehow...

Comment: @AS Identifying individual words or phrases as one thing or another does not change the actual behavior of speakers. Terminology  is made up by specialists for special purposes; it's not something you can determine by inspection (or look up in a dictionary). "Phrasal verb" is a term with a very specific meaning, but it gets used in a lot of different ways; similar remarks for all other grammar terms.

Comment: The reason y0u can say "I took the elevator up" but not "I climbed the mountain up" is that the mountain doesn't actually go up, but the elevator does.  Consider *I showed the visitor up, I threw the ball up, I ran the flag up, I took the letter up*, etc.

Comment: I will pedantically observe that you can "look up it," but that means, for instance, getting under a pipe and looking upwards to see what you can see through or in it.

Comment: Trying to find out how come "He climbed the mountain up" is ungrammatical has a difficulty specific to the verb "climb". "Climb" *implies* upward motion unless context implies otherwise. So it could be argued that if you meant no more than "He climbed the mountain up", you wouldn't bother saying the word "up". Try "He retraced the route up" (talking about the route someone else had taken up a mountain).

Comment: My first thought was that all this discussion seemed pointless since the word "up" is quite unnecessary anyway. Why not simply say "I climbed the mountain"? Everyone knows that that involves going upwards. However having looked at the French, which can often be helpful, while the verbs *ascendre* or *monter* would not take prepositions, *grimper* does.  *Grimper à* is translated as "to climb up". It may be that the sense of "climb up" focuses more on the action of climbing - a bit like French  *grimper*.

Comment: @RosieF So "Up" is just a redundant and that makes the sentence ungrammatical?  That sounds reasonable, but I wonder why everyone says different answers.

Comment: @WS2 I'm trying to figure out the grammar behind this sentence, so I can apply the grammar when I make sentences and avoid making grammar mistake.

Comment: @AS Look at John Lawler's comment. I think that will tell you all you need to know.

Comment: @PeterShor The reason y0u can say "I took the elevator up" but not "I climbed the mountain up" is that the mountain doesn't actually go up, but the elevator does.  I can not understand this.  Adverbs describe verbs.  "Up" describes "Climb," not "Mountain."  Why does the mountain have to be able to move up in order to use "Up"?

Comment: Parts of speech don't necessarily just coordinate with one other element. A transitive verb needs ***two*** other elements. You can say *He surprised my sister*, but if you leave out either *my sister* or *he*, it becomes ungrammatical. In this construction, where you put *up/down/out* after the direct object, the adverb must coordinate both with the verb and with the direct object. So, for example, you can say *I took the dog out* but not *I climbed the window out*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer**

The Original Poster is 100% absolutely correct that if *up* was an adverb functioning as an Adjunct (read Adverbial), it should be able to come after the Direct Object. However, it is not an adverb, and it is not an Adjunct either.

You can't say *He climbed the mountain up* because *the mountain* is not a Complement of the verb *climb*, but of the preposition *up*, and so must come after it. Together, the two items form a single preposition phrase *up the mountain.* It is this preposition phrase which is the Complement of the verb *climb*.

With a 'phrasal verb' idiom such as *put something on*, the verb *put* takes two separate Complements: an Object, a noun phrase, and a Locative Complement, a preposition phrase. The order these two separate complements appear in is not fixed although it is subject to certain restrictions concerning their comparative length and whether the Object is a pronoun.

---

**Full answer:**

Think about the verb *put*. This verb creates slots for different types of Complement. Apart from the person or thing doing the putting (the Subject), it creates a slot for the thing being moved (the Direct Object) and a slot for the destination of that thing (the Locative Complement).

If one of those Complements is missing, the clause is likely to be ungrammatical:

1. *He put the pen. (no destination, wrong)
2. *He put on the table. (no thing, wrong)
3. He put the pen on the table. (grammatical)

In the example above *the pen* and *on the table* are two separate Complements of the verb.

In contrast, the verb *loved* often takes just one Complement, the thing appreciated or adored:

4. I love reggae.

So different verbs take different types and numbers of Complements. And this often depends on the type of construction that they enter into.

When a verb's Complements are very short, it can be a bit difficult to discern what's going on. This difficulty increases when the verb enters into an idiomatic construction.

Before we look at some different constructions that have been confusing us here, it's important to note that many other types of word also take Complements. Nouns can take Complements:

5. the sacking [of the managing director]
6. the idea [that pigs can fly]
7. the desire [to lick the cream of the top of the pudding]

And importantly for us here, prepositions can take different types of Complement too, and may also take none. Here are examples with *before*:

8. I'd met her before <sup>no Complement</sup>
9. I'd met her before [the concert] <sup>noun phrase Complement</sup>
10. I'd met her before [the concert started] <sup>finite clause as Complement</sup>

If you're unlucky, you might be using a grammar that basically ignores everything we've learned about the English language in the last two hundred years. In that case, you may feel that the *before* in (7) is an adverb, the one in (8) a preposition and the one in (9) a subordinating conjunction. Bad luck there. They are all the same word - which is what you thought before you learned they were different. So good news in a way: You were right all along!

The last point for now, some prepositions can take other preposition phrases as Complements:

11. He pulled the rabbit [out [of the hat]].

Here the preposition *out* is taking an *of*-preposition phrase as a Complement.

---

**The Original Poster's question:**

So let's get down to business. The verb *climb* takes a preposition phrase as a Complement. It tells you the destination of the climber:

12. I climbed [up the mountain]
13. I climbed [up]

In both the examples above the *up*-preposition phrase tells you the end destination of the climber. In (12) *up* takes a noun phrase Complement. This is not a Complement of the verb, but of the preposition. For that reason, it must come after the preposition and not before it! In (13), *up* takes no Complement, but the information that would be supplied by a complement  must be available from the context.

This is very different from the complementation pattern of the verbs in so-called "phrasal verbs." Consider the idiom *put something on*, meaning to put something on your body and begin to wear it.  In this construction the verb *put* takes two Complements, a Direct Object and Locative Complement. The Direct Object is the thing being moved or manipulated onto the body, and the Locative Complement is the preposition phrase beginning with *on*, usually just one word:

14. He put [the hat] [on <s>his head</s>]
15. He put [on <s>his head</s>] [the hat]

Here the noun phrase one might expect after the preposition *on* is usually missing because we know what the person put the clothing onto: their body or the relevant part of their body. Most importantly *the hat* is NOT the syntactic object of the preposition *on* or the "multiword verb/phrasal verb" *put on*.

With idioms like this (maybe the right word here is *constructions*, not *idioms*, but that's a different discussion), if the Direct Object of the verb is a pronoun, and not stressed, it must come before the Locative Complement. This follows a general principle that Objects naturally occur closer to the verb than Locative Complements, unless they are long, or prominent. But notice that the key point here is that the Object and the Locative Complement are two different Complements of the verb.

@Peter Shor discusses the following example:

16. I took the elevator up.

This is an example of a construction in which *take* takes a mode of transport and a path as two separate Complements. The first is a noun phrase functioning as Direct Object  and the second a preposition phrase Complement. The order of the Complements in this construction is fixed. The Direct Object must come first:

17. He took the train to Paris
18. She took the plane to Madrid.
19. Bob took the ski-lift up the mountain
20. Bob took the sk-lift up.
21. Peter Shor took the elevator [up [to the top of the elevator shaft]]
22. Peter Shor took the elevator [up [to the top floor]
23. Peter Shor took the elevator [to the top of the building]
24. Peter Shor took the elevator [up the Empire State Building]
25. Peter Shor took the elevator up [<s>from where it started</s>]

Notice that everything is much more difficult - as demonstrated in the comments - if we treat intransitive prepositions as adverbs!

Comment: Yeah, I definitely don't see why *climbing up a mountain* would be any different from *climbing down a hole* or *climbing out a window* or *climbing under a tree* or *climbing into bed* or *climbing inside a box* or *climbing over a fence*. Jury might return a different verdict for *climbing in December* or *climbing in a tuxedo* or *climbing in mittens* or *climbing in your birthday suit*, though they shouldn't.

Comment: @tchrist In the latter examples, the PPs are Adjuncts/Adverbials/embellishments, but in the former they're complements. So maybe they oughta. (You can do tests for this using the preform phrase *do so*. This must semantically include complements which are then ungrammatical if they are stuck back on or are different. *Tchrist climbed up Everest, but Mitch did so up the Eiger* is ungrammatical. However, *Tchrist climbed Everest in his Abba t-shirt, but Mitch did so in his birthday suit* is fine. (Sorry, Mitch)

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. _so cold_

Comment: @Mitch Well, you see, you should have worn boots.

Comment: *Notice that everything is much more difficult ... if we treat intransitive prepositions as adverbs!* Difficulty should never be a reason to invent an excuse. A preposition's function is to modify a noun - work that a prefix or suffix might do in an agglutinative language or otherwise be done by a grammatical case. An intransitive preposition is a contradiction in terms.

Comment: @Greybeard We've known for over a hundred years that that conception of a word class is silly. Additionally, there are no arguments to support the analysis that *up* is an adverb. It was only ever thought to be an adverb because of the mistakes that were made with prepositions and so we did not know where to put it. I favour ditching the preposition label altogether. The class of words that actually exists might be called "orientives" or something like that.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. I have long hoped for the advent of a Linneus to categorise English. So far I have been given Pullam and Huddleston whose "grammar" (used in the widest possible sense) seems to be little more than smoke and mirrors. "Intransitive prepositions" indeed!

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.  Thank you for the long answer.  But why is "Up" not an adverb?  All dictionaries list "Up" as an adverb.  If you mean "Up" does not function as an adverb in the sentence "He climbed the mountain up,"  that's what I want to know.

Comment: @AS We should never get our grammar information from dictionaries! It's not what they're for. [See here for some properties of prepositions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/468152/what-part-of-speech-is-back-in-if-you-want-it-back/468176#468176). But, if you think about it, your question is also evidence that *up* is not an adverb!

Comment: @AS DSW already explained to you in their answer to your previous question! But here goes: 1 Morhpologically unlike an adverb 2. Can be the complement of the verb *be*. 3. Can take a noun as a complement. 4. Can take preposition phrases as complements 5. Can't be modified by *very*. 6. Can be modified by *straight* 7. Can be modified by *right* 9. Can postmodify nouns. 10. Coordinates with other preposition phrases. 11. Can't modify adjectives or other adverbs. 12. Can appear as complement of verbs such as *put.* 13. Won't feely coordinate with actual adverbs.

Comment: @AS Btw, [here's why we should get our grammar info from dictionaries :)](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6609/calling-out-a-comment-dictionaries-are-bad-sources-for-determining-words-part/6635#6635)

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. "He climbed the mountain up" is grammatically incorrect because "Up" is not an adverb?  Are there other reasons why "He climbed the mountain up" is grammatically incorrect?  And how does it sound?  Several people said "Up" is redundant as "Climb" implies upward movement.  What are those examples in the dictionaries that are written using "Up" as an adverb?  Are those "Up" all particles of phrasal verbs?  Do dictionaries list particles as adverbs?  Are following sentences correct?  "He climbed the mountain slowly," "He climbed the mountain every weekend."